# Update AJAX/ PHP VAR with newly received data.id

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax

So on a first call of AJAX to my database I use the Ajax var as the php variable

Like so `var notification_id="<?php echo $notification['notification_id']?>";`

But after the first call.. And IF only new data is received, how can that new notification_id be sent back from the success to replace that var? At the moment the same call with the same notification_id is going over and over. But lets say someone deletes a notification for whatever reason or updates, the initial call will no longer be the max notification_id so obviously MUST change.

So I did some research and came across this which is what I think updates it. Only I put it inside my success each loop and nothing happened.

`notification_id = notification.notification_id;`

**CLIENT SIDE AJAX**

```
success: function(response){
       $.each(response.notification, function(i, notification) {
  if(notification.notification_id > notification_id){
$("#newnotif"+ notification_id).prepend('MY CONTENT');
      i = parseInt($("#mes").text()); $("#mes").text((i+notification.num));
  }
  notification_id = notification.notification_id; 
            });

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I have fixed it.

The issue was I put my function outside my vars and not beneath them. And I hadn't put `notification_id = notification.notification_id;` inside the each loop.